# Can I use a ClassMap for writing with CsvHelper?

Tags: csvhelper

I am attempting to use CsvHelper to improve my manual conversion process from objects to csv records/rows. I have created a complex `ClassMap` that I wanted to use to write a list of objects out to a file. How can I add the `ClassMap` to the CsvHelper instance's Configuration for writing?

I am getting the following exception and message now:

```
public class SpecimenMap : ClassMap<Specimen>
{
    public SpecimenMap()
    {
        Map(s =>
                DataFunctions.GetSiteByName(s.SiteName).RecordNo.ToString() + "-" +
                    s.SpecimenNumber.ToString()).
                    Index(0).Name("recordNumber");

        Map(s => 
                s.RecordNo.ToString()).
                    Index(1).Name("specimenNumber");
```

/* many more, but I set a breakpoint on the first 'Map' and it throws the exception. I also tried commenting out the first 'Map' and running the second (since the first includes calls to external functions), it had identical results. */
....

```
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(localFileLocation))
        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
        {
            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<SpecimenMap>(); // this line throws exception
            csv.WriteRecords(specimen);
        }
```

Exception Thrown:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No members were found in expression
>   '{expression}'.

In my research I found this code but I don't know how to interpret the exception. Something about the Stack size after doing some kind of Reflection (Line 34).
https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/ClassMap%601.cs

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error you are getting is telling you that the `Map()` function expects to only get a class member from it's expression. `Map(s => s.SiteName)`.  If you want to further manipulate the output, you can use `ConvertUsing()`.

**Updated** for Version 27.2.1. `ClassMap` is registered on the `Context` and `ConvertUsing()` has been changed to `Convert()`.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{    
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var specimen = new List<Specimen> { new Specimen { SiteName = "DeepThought", SpecimenNumber = 1 } };

        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<SpecimenMap>();

        csv.WriteRecords(specimen);

        Console.Read();
    }            
}

public sealed class SpecimenMap : ClassMap<Specimen>
{
    public SpecimenMap()
    {
        Map(s => s.SiteName).Index(0).Name("recordNumber").Convert(s => GetSiteByName(s.Value.SiteName) + "-" + s.Value.SpecimenNumber);
        Map(s => s.SpecimenNumber).Index(1).Name("specimenNumber");
    }
}

public class Specimen
{
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    public int SpecimenNumber { get; set; }
}

public static int GetSiteByName(string siteName)
{
    if (siteName == "DeepThought")
    {
        return 42;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

**Original**

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{    
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out))
    {
        var specimen = new List<Specimen> { new Specimen { SiteName = "DeepThought", SpecimenNumber = 1 } };

        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<SpecimenMap>();

        csv.WriteRecords(specimen);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }            
}

public sealed class SpecimenMap : ClassMap<Specimen>
{
    public SpecimenMap()
    {
        Map(s => s.SiteName).Index(0).Name("recordNumber").ConvertUsing(s => GetSiteByName(s.SiteName) + "-" + s.SpecimenNumber);
        Map(s => s.SpecimenNumber).Index(1).Name("specimenNumber");
    }
}

public class Specimen
{
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    public int SpecimenNumber { get; set; }
}

public static int GetSiteByName(string siteName)
{
    if (siteName == "DeepThought")
    {
        return 42;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Juts an FYI for anyone finding this, I had to use  `objCsvWriter.Context.RegisterClassMap<EmailRecordMap>();`

Comment: All ClassMaps should be a sealed class:  https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/2101