# Custom header format with CSVHelper

Tags: .net, csvhelper

I need to write a CSV file with headers in camel case.

Imagine we have this class

```cs
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And the following code

```cs
public void Main()
{
    var p = new Person { Id = 1, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
    
    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, true))
    {
        csv.WriteHeader<Person>();
        csv.NextRecord();
        csv.WriteRecord(p);
        csv.Flush();
        var newRecord = writer.ToString();
        newRecord.Dump();
    }
}
```

This will output the following

```
Id,FirstName,LastName
1,John,Doe
```

I would like the header to be camel case formatted

```
id,firstName,lastName
1,John,Doe
```

Last important thing is, I don't know the objects so ClassMaps or attributes are not an options.

Is there a way to configure how the header are formatted with CSVHelper ?

Comment: You can use [`[Name("firstName")]`](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/attributes/) to control column names at compile time as shown in [Change the name of headers in CSV file using CSVHelper in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38044320/3744182).  Or in runtime you can use a `ClassMap<T>` as shown in [Can I use a ClassMap for writing with CsvHelper?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55795326/3744182)?  Is that all you want? Or are you looking for some generic way to camelCase your column names en masse without having to specify each one individually?

Comment: I don't know the format of the objects I will receive so Attributes and ClassMaps are not the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `DefaultClassMap<T>` this should work for any class you provide.

```cs
public void Main()
{
    var p = new Person { Id = 1, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
    
    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, true))
    {
        var map = new DefaultClassMap<Person>();
        
        map.AutoMap(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        
        foreach (var memberMap in map.MemberMaps)
        {
            memberMap.Data.Names.Add(System.Text.Json.JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase.ConvertName(memberMap.Data.Member.Name));
        }
        
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap(map);
        
        csv.WriteHeader<Person>();
        csv.NextRecord();
        csv.WriteRecord(p);
        csv.Flush();
        var newRecord = writer.ToString();
        newRecord.Dump();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```